# Email helper authentication

Tags: c#, email, authentication

i am creating an email helper that sends out emails, this is working fine and all but i need to pass through the current users username and password.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

I have used `Environment.UserName;` and this gets the username correctly but i do not know how to get the password.

Here is what i am doing for the email helper.

```
public void SendEmail(int port, string host, string displayName, string subject, string body, string addressFrom, string addressTo, string password, string username)
        {
            MailMessage messageToSend = new MailMessage();
            messageToSend .Subject = subject;
            messageToSend .Body = body;
            messageToSend .From = new MailAddress(addressFrom, displayName);
            messageToSend .To.Add(addressTo);
            messageToSend .Priority = MailPriority.High;
            messageToSend .IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient SMTPclient = new SmtpClient(Host, Port);
            SMTPclient .EnableSsl = false;
        SMTPclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
            SMTPclient.Send(message);
        }
```

Comment: You have `new NetworkCredential(Username, Password)` and the method parameters `string password, string username` with lower case. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can get the password, but you actually don't need the password, you need the [credentials for current user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials.aspx), which you can get and assigned to your SMTPclient as follows

```
SMTPclient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Comment: I have tried that but it does not work, getting this error when trying to send the email: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender.

Comment: So, in that case check that current user has the permission on server.

Comment: @johnnie is your SMTP an MS Exchange? Other than that the 5.7.1 error code sounds like you are trying to relay a message thru that SMTPd but it doesn't let you to do it, simply because its configured to do so. I think your ip address/netmask isn't set to allowed relay list on the SMTP config. Did you try your code using a different SMTP server?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can retrieve currently logged user password!!
Windows stores an hash of the password, not password itself.